# problems parsing text in python

Tags: python, parsing

I wrote a short Python script that parses a text file in order to pull out all words that are between 4 and 8 letters long, then writes them to another text file. Each word should be in quotes followed by a comma. To test the script, I grabbed a paragraph of text from a lorem ipsum generator. The output, however is not consistent with the specs of the script. I will explain the discrepancies under the script output below.

Here is the code:

```
import re


with open('loremipsum.txt') as file:
    lines = file.read()

blacklist = [" ", ",", "."]

step_1 = re.split('. | , | ', lines)

with open('ipsumWords.txt', 'w') as f:
    for word in step_1:
        if not word in blacklist:
            if (len(word) > 3 and len(word) < 9):
                f.write("'")
                f.write(word)
                f.write("'")
                f.write(",")
```

Here is a short sample of the input file:

Gourds watermelon. Post pounder calf, hay or duck is, tool shed horse. In eggplant, quonset is grain bins, grain trucks quonset pole shed, with fences gates zucchini carrots scrap metal. Peacocks baa ostriches owls. Kidney beans ostrich trucks. Gourds utters at welding equipment a oink oink haybine. Apples ducks straw, quail a ostriches donkey, hay hook cucumbers. Kidney beans ostrich trucks. Combine Harvester swather, baler as haybine parsley, melon in ha.

This is what the output looks like:

'Gourd','pounde','calf','horse','eggplant','quonse','grai','bins','grai','truck','quonse','shed','fence','gate','zucchin','carrot','scra','metal','Peacock','ostriche','owls','Kidne','bean','ostric','trucks','Gourd','utter','weldin','equipmen','haybine','Apple','duck','straw','quai','ostriche','donkey','Kidne','bean','ostric','trucks','Combin','Harveste','swather','bale','haybin','parsley','melo',

There are a couple problems with the output. I will give one example of each category of the issues.
1. Some words like "pounder" have the last letter truncated and become "pounde"
2. The word ostriches is not only has the s truncated, it would be 9 letters long if spelled correctly

Comment: Do you have to use regex?

Comment: I guess I don't have to, but it seemed to be a good way to split a line of text on more than one delimiter. If there are better ways to do that I am all ears.

Comment: I would suggest printing out the contents of step_1 right after you set it, to make sure that the re.split is doing what you expect.

Comment: That is good advice! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is the regular expression in this line:

```
step_1 = re.split('. | , | ', lines)
```

Remember that `.` in a regular expression means "any character", so the expression `.<space>` means "any character followed by space". This is why some words appear to be truncated: taking `ostriches`, for example, the `s` on the end matches your `.<space>` expression, so the string gets split at that point with `ostriche` on the left side of the split.

Also remember that whitespace is significant, so the expression `<space>,<space>` will only match a comma with spaces on either side of it, which is probably not what you mean.

If you want to split on periods, commas, and spaces, you would need something like:

```
step_1 = re.split('[.,]? ')
```

This will split words on whitespace, optionally preceded by either `.` or `,`.

This results in `step_1` having the value:

```
>>> step_1
['Gourds', 'watermelon', 'Post', 'pounder', 'calf', 'hay', 'or',
'duck', 'is', 'tool', 'shed', 'horse', 'In', 'eggplant', 'quonset',
'is', 'grain', 'bins', 'grain', 'trucks', 'quonset', 'pole', 'shed',
'with', 'fences', 'gates', 'zucchini', 'carrots', 'scrap', 'metal',
'Peacocks', 'baa', 'ostriches', 'owls', 'Kidney', 'beans', 'ostrich',
'trucks', 'Gourds', 'utters', 'at', 'welding', 'equipment', 'a',
'oink', 'oink', 'haybine', 'Apples', 'ducks', 'straw', 'quail', 'a',
'ostriches', 'donkey', 'hay', 'hook', 'cucumbers', 'Kidney', 'beans',
'ostrich', 'trucks', 'Combine', 'Harvester', 'swather', 'baler', 'as',
'haybine', 'parsley', 'melon', 'in', 'ha.\n']
```

This should get you closer to what you want.

Comment: That did the trick! I was not aware of the significance of the .  That is worth making note of!! Thanks man!!